# Is this Hashset lock threadsafe?

Tags: c#, concurrency, locking, hashset

```cs
private static readonly object MyMethodLockobject = new object();
private static readonly HashSet<long> ActiveWorkItem = new HashSet<long>();


public async Task MyMethod(long id)
{
    lock (MyMethodLockobject)
    {
        if (ActiveWorkItem.Contains(id))
        {
            throw new AnotherRequestAlreadyInProgressException();
        }

        ActiveWorkItem.Add(id);
    }

    try
    {
        return await DoWork(id);
    }
    finally
    {
        ActiveWorkItem.Remove(id);
    }
}
```

ActiveWorkItem purpose is preventing concurrent calls on same id. only add contain and remove are needed.
MyMethod is the only place with ActiveWorkItem access.

my concern is this line:

```cs
    finally
    {
        ActiveWorkItem.Remove(id);
    }
```

or is is necessary to change to

```cs
    finally
    {
        lock (MyMethodLockobject)
            {
                ActiveWorkItem.Remove(id);
            }
    }
```

better alternative also appreciated

Comment: No, it isn't thread safe. You need to do all manipulation of the Hashset within a lock.

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary` would be better (faster+easier) than this kind of lock. To implement it property with `HashSet` use some implementation of `ReaderWriterLock` for all points of interaction with the collection, not only for this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is necessary to protect the `HashSet` inside the `finally` block too.

```
finally
{
    lock (MyMethodLockobject) ActiveWorkItem.Remove(id);
}
```

Otherwise one thread may be adding items to the `HashSet` while multiple threads are concurrently removing items from the same `HashSet`, potentially putting the object into a corrupted state, and resulting to undefined behavior.